# Image download in android from server using jsp

Tags: android, jsp

I want to read an image using jsp and send over http to be accessed by an android application.

Code i tried for JSP is by adding data as header

```
String strDirectory = "D://abc.jpg";
File fp = new File(strDirectory);
int length = (int)fp.length();
buffer = new byte[length];
FileInputStream f0 = new FileInputStream(fp);
f0.read(buffer);  
f0.close(); 
response.addHeader("image_data",new String(buffer));
```

I dont know if this is correct.
Whats the right way to send image bytes from a jsp page to android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it is the right way honestly.
First of all i suggest you to use a servlet if you can otherwise
you have an implicit object called response and then

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ( f0.read(buffer) != -1)
   os.write(buffer);
.....
```

before this code you have to set correctly response header like:

```
response.setContentType("your contente type here");
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thankyou it worked..before this i just used out.println() and read it in android..it did not work..can you tell me why ?? is that because only ASCII characters can be printed

Comment: out.println() is used just for text not for byte stream